# How to get last conversations in xmpp chat server using javascript

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I am new to XMPP. I have created a xmpp chat application using javascript. As of now, i am able to send and receive messages from or to the users using the following code.

```
jQuery.xmpp.connect({
        url: url,
        jid: sessionUserId,
        password: password
        onConnect: function () 
           console.log("Xmpp Connected");
           jQuery.xmpp.setPresence(null);
        },
        onPresence: function (presence) {

        },
        onMessage: function (message) {

        }
     });
```

Now I need to get last 20 conversations between two users.I had referred history in this link, and i have no idea how to use it. How can we do that. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by last 20 conversations between two users ? Do you mean messages ? Which link are you talking about ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMPP query archive by latest messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828955/xmpp-query-archive-by-latest-messages)