# XMPP query archive by latest messages

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm reading http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html to query Ejabberd for messages archived with a certain user.

This is the xml that I'm sending:

```
<iq type='get' id='get_archive_user1'>
 <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'>
  <with>user1@localhost</with>
  <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
   <max>20</max>
  </set>
 </query>
</iq>
```

I'm receiving the first 20 messages correctly. To request again I'm adding the tag:

```
<after>(id in element "Last" from last request)</after>
```

and this also work fine. What I need is to receive the last 20 messages, not the first 20 messages. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[XEP-0313 Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) rely on [XEP-0059 Result Set Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0059.html) for pagination.

RSM specification explains [how to get the last page in a Result Set](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0059.html#last):

> The requesting entity MAY ask for the last page in a result set by including in its request an empty `<before/>` element, and the maximum number of items to return.

It means you need to add an empty `<before/>` element in your result set query.

Here is an example based on XEP-0313 version 0.4 on how to get the last 20 messages in a conversation with a given user. The query limit is defined by the parameter `max` (it defined the size of the pages).

```
<iq type='set' id='q29302'>
  <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
      <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
        <value>urn:xmpp:mam:0</value>
      </field>
      <field var='with'>
        <value>juliet@capulet.lit</value>
      </field>
    </x>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
     <max>20</max>
     <before/>
    </set>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Comment: thank you very much. This works exactly as I expected. To load the next 20 messages I'm adding <before>(First Message ID of last request)</before> and it's also working fine!

Comment: Mickael do you know if this xml should work exactly the same way to request MUC messages? I just used the same xml and replaced the user jid with the room jid. It returns 0 but I can see the messages on ejabberd database table archive

Answer (score 6):

You should add an empty `<before/>` element:

```xml
<iq type='get' id='get_archive_user1'>
    <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'>
        <with>user1@localhost</with>
        <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
            <max>20</max>
            <before/>
        </set>
    </query>
</iq>
```

See [here](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0059.html#last).

Answer (score 4):

People who would like to use Smack to fetch this can use below code

```
 public MamManager.MamQueryResult getArchivedMessages(String jid, int maxResults) {

        MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        try {
            DataForm form = new DataForm(DataForm.Type.submit);
            FormField field = new FormField(FormField.FORM_TYPE);
            field.setType(FormField.Type.hidden);
            field.addValue(MamElements.NAMESPACE);
            form.addField(field);

            FormField formField = new FormField("with");
            formField.addValue(jid);
            form.addField(formField);

            // "" empty string for before
            RSMSet rsmSet = new RSMSet(maxResults, "", RSMSet.PageDirection.before);
            MamManager.MamQueryResult mamQueryResult = mamManager.page(form, rsmSet);

            return mamQueryResult;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: i'm getting cannot resolve symbol MamManager, how to solve it?

Comment: @gaurang, I guess you need to add smack-experimental as dependancy. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.igniterealtime.smack/smack-experimental